# NodeJS, Express and SQLite: handling error messages?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express

I'm using POSTMAN to send post requests with a JSON object to my nodejs express server.

below is the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); //need this to get req.body into json

var path = require('path');
var server = require('http').Server(app);

var sqlite = require("better-sqlite3");
var db = new sqlite("bankdatabase.db");


onst createCustomerDBStatement = db.prepare('INSERT INTO customers(firstname, lastname, ssn) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');

app.post('/createaccount', function(req, res){

    var successOrFailed = "success";
    var createBankAccountRequest = req.body;
    console.log(createBankAccountRequest);

    var rows = db.prepare(`SELECT * FROM customers WHERE ssn = ${createBankAccountRequest.SSN}`).all();

    console.log(rows);

    if (rows.length > 0) {

        console.log("Customer exists already");

    } else {

        createCustomerDBStatement.run(createBankAccountRequest.FirstName, createBankAccountRequest.LastName, createBankAccountRequest.SSN);
    };


    var createBankAccountResponse = {status: successOrFailed, "account number": bankAccountNumber, "customer id": customerID};

    res.json(createBankAccountResponse); 

});
```

Right now, if there's a problem with my sql query, then I get an error message thrown on both my command line console and on the POSTMAN app/program.

How do I go about writing a custom error message AND also doing something if there's an error?

For my program above, if there's an error, I want to set `var successOrNot = "failed"` and send them in my `res.json`

Also, when there's an error with the sql query, `res.json` seems to not send.

I've tried this:

```
const createCustomerDBStatement = db.prepare('INSERT INTO accounts(customerid, accountnumber, accounttype, balance) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('ERROR!', err);
            successOrFailed = "failed";
        } else {
            successOrFailed = "success";
        };
    });
```

but it didn't do anything.

Comment: I don't see any `stmt.run()` or `stmt.finalize()` calls once you've prepared your "prepared statement".

Comment: @Paulsm4, I have this under the 'else' statement: createCustomerDBStatement.run(createBankAccountRequest.FirstName, createBankAccountRequest.LastName, createBankAccountRequest.SSN);

Answer (score 0):

> **Error Handling**
>
> Error Handling refers to how Express catches and processes errors that
>   occur both synchronously and asynchronously. Express comes with a
>   default error handler so you don’t need to write your own to get
>   started.
>
> **Catching Errors**
>
> It’s important to ensure that Express catches all errors that occur
>   while running route handlers and middleware.
>
> Errors that occur in synchronous code inside route handlers and
>   middleware require no extra work. If synchronous code throws an error,
>   then Express will catch and process it.
>
> **The default error handler**
>
> Express comes with a built-in error handler that takes care of any
>   errors that might be encountered in the app. This default
>   error-handling middleware function is added at the end of the
>   middleware function stack.
>
> If you pass an error to next() and you do not handle it in a custom
>   error handler, it will be handled by the built-in error handler; the
>   error will be written to the client with the stack trace. The stack
>   trace is not included in the production environment.
>
> If you call next() with an error after you have started writing the
>   response (for example, if you encounter an error while streaming the
>   response to the client) the Express default error handler closes the
>   connection and fails the request.
>
> So when you add a custom error handler, you must delegate to the
>   default Express error handler, when the headers have already been sent
>   to the client:

```
 function errorHandler (err, req, res, next) {
  if (res.headersSent) {
    return next(err)
  }
  res.status(500)
  res.render('error', { error: err })
}
```

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html